# FIeld format conversion error in numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to create a numpy array consisting of an array of data, where each data point is another array of length 5. I am trying to do this by setting a first datum (i.e. array of five elements) and setting the name and formats of each data types using the following code:

```
DTYPE = [('t_start', 'S32'), ('t_end', 'S32'), ('mac1', 'S32'), ('mac2', 'S32'), ('rss', np.float)]

np.array([ ['2020-10-07 09:20:00', '2020-10-07 09:43:20', 'b8:9a:2a:06:68:f5', 'b8:9a:2a:06:68:f5', '10.501'] ], dtype=DTYPE)
```

There must be something really obvious I am missing here because this (simple?) code issues the following Exception

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2020-10-07 09:20:00'
```

Any hint on what is going on here would be much appreciated.

Comment: you are passing `DTYPE` to `np.array` and in `DTYPE` you called `np.float` so python will try to cast `2020-10-07 09:20:00 ` to `float` , and it is impossible for python

Comment: @Hosseinreza thanks! However, the error still persists if I use `'f8'`instead of `np.float`

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your exact error message, but it looks like there are two issues: your inner list should be a tuple, and you should use `U` (Unicode string) in place of `S` in the format specifier ([documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html) says that `S` (zero-terminated bytes) is not recommended):

```
import numpy as np

DTYPE = [('t_start', 'U32'), ('t_end', 'U32'), ('mac1', 'U32'), 
         ('mac2', 'U32'), ('rss', np.float)]

values = [('2020-10-07 09:20:00', '2020-10-07 09:43:20', 
           'b8:9a:2a:06:68:f5', 'b8:9a:2a:06:68:f5', '10.501')]

arr = np.array(values, dtype=DTYPE)

print(arr.shape)

print(arr[0]['t_end'])  # 2020-10-07 09:43:20
print(type(arr[0]['t_end']))  # <class 'numpy.str_'>

print(arr[0]['rss'])  # 10.501
print(type(arr[0]['rss']))  # <class 'numpy.float64'>
```

In general, in your input to `np.array`, use an inner *tuple* to group the elements of each compound data item, and use *lists* to group the data items into an array of appropriate dimensionality.